# How are the brand words Sega and Segafredo interpreted in Italy?

Tags: word-meaning

I heard the word "sega" is rude in Italian, and that Sega, the video game company, had marketing difficulties because of this. But isn't there also a coffee company named Segafredo operating in Italy? Last I heard Segafredo was huge and popular. Does that company's name also elicit sniggers? Or does it make a big difference that in this case sega is only part of the word?

Comment: This looks like a kind of opinion-based (or hearsay-based) question. I can't imagine a possible objective answer to it (the number of sniggers/day elicited by Segafredo vs. those elicited by Lavazza?).